# Unable to insert into database after submit

Tags: php

```
<?php
include("database.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$category=$_POST["category"];
$ittitle=$_POST["ittitle"];
$itname=$_POST["itname"];
$itrole=$_POST["itrole"];
$itsalary=$_POST["itsalary"];

$btitle=$_POST["btitle"];
$bname=$_POST["bname"];
$brole=$_POST["brole"];
$bsalary=$_POST["bsalary"];

$gtitle=$_POST["gtitle"];
$gname=$_POST["gname"];
$grole=$_POST["grole"];
$gsalary=$_POST["gsalary"];

$result=mysql_query("insert into test(ittitle,itname,itrole,itsalary,btitle,bname,brole,bsalary,gtitle,gname,grole,gsalary)values('$_POST[ittitle]','$_POST[itname]','$_POST[itrole]','$_POST[itsalary]','$_POST[btitle]','$_POST[bname]','$_POST[brole]','$_POST[bsalary]','$_POST[gtitle]','$_POST[gname]','$_POST[grole]','$_POST[gsalary]')");

echo "Inserted Successfully";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Using Selectbox</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;

    }
    .it{ background: white; }
    .bank{ background: white; }
    .govt{ background: white; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select").change(function(){
            $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=="it"){
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".it").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="bank"){
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".bank").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="govt"){
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".govt").show();
                }
            });
        }).change();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select name="category">
            <option>Choose Category</option>
            <option value="it">it</option>
            <option value="bank">bank</option>
            <option value="govt">govt</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="it box"><table border="1" style="width:250px">
<tr>
<td><b>Title</td>
<td><input type="text" name="ittitle"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b> IT Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="itname"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b> IT Job Role</td>
<td><input type="text" name="itrole"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b> IT Salary</td>
<td><input type="text" name="itsalary"></td></tr>



</table></div>

<div class="bank box"><table border="1" style="width:250px">
<tr>
<td><b>Title</td>
<td><input type="text" name="btitle"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b> Bank Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="bname"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b> Bank Job Role</td>
<td><input type="text" name="brole"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b> Bank Salary</td>
<td><input type="text" name="bsalary"></td></tr>



</table></div>

<div class="govt box"><table border="1" style="width:250px">
<tr>
<td><b>Title</td>
<td><input type="text" name="gtitle"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b> Govt Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="gname"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b> Govt Job Role</td>
<td><input type="text" name="grole"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b> Govt Salary</td>
<td><input type="text" name="gsalary"></td></tr>
</table></div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Unable to insert into database after submit.Please tell me changes required.

Comment: why won't you use your `$variables` as your values?

Comment: how to use.will u tell me

Comment: You don't have any `<form></form>` tags, nor action, nor method etc.

Comment: Lack of database escaping and error checking. Instead of subverting the question quality filter; you could have added a few more details about your prior debugging attempts.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and  `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`

Comment: VALUES ('$category', '$ittitle') that's how simple it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no form in  code. Define  and its method as method="post"

Comment: how to write if condition to insert particular form  based on category

Answer (score 0):

There are many things you need to change, but to solve it for now, you need to fix the mysql_query to this (Notice the brackets):

$result=mysql_query("insert into test(ittitle,itname,itrole,itsalary,btitle,bname,brole,bsalary,gtitle,gname,grole,gsalary)values('{$_POST["ittitle"]}','**{$_POST["itname"]}**','{$_POST["itrole"]}','{$_POST["itsalary"]}','{$_POST["btitle"]}','{$_POST["bname"]}','{$_POST["brole"]}','{$_POST["bsalary"]}','{$_POST["gtitle"]}','{$_POST["gname"]}','{$_POST["grole"]}','{$_POST["gsalary"]}')");

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include("database.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$category=$_POST["category"];

$ittitle=$_POST["ittitle"];
$itname=$_POST["itname"];
$itrole=$_POST["itrole"];
$itsalary=$_POST["itsalary"];

$btitle=$_POST["btitle"];
$bname=$_POST["bname"];
$brole=$_POST["brole"];
$bsalary=$_POST["bsalary"];

$gtitle=$_POST["gtitle"];
$gname=$_POST["gname"];
$grole=$_POST["grole"];
$gsalary=$_POST["gsalary"];

$result=mysql_query("insert into test(ittitle,itname,itrole,itsalary,btitle,bname,brole,bsalary,gtitle,gname,grole,gsalary)values('$_POST[ittitle]','$_POST[itname]','$_POST[itrole]','$_POST[itsalary]','$_POST[btitle]','$_POST[bname]','$_POST[brole]','$_POST[bsalary]','$_POST[gtitle]','$_POST[gname]','$_POST[grole]','$_POST[gsalary]')");

echo "Inserted Successfully";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Using Selectbox</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;

    }
    .it{ background: white; }
    .bank{ background: white; }
    .govt{ background: white; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select").change(function(){
            $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=="it"){
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".it").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="bank"){
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".bank").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="govt"){
                    $(".box").hide();
                    $(".govt").show();
                }
            });
        }).change();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="get" name="form1">
    <div>
        <select name="category">
            <option>Choose Category</option>
            <option value="it">it</option>
            <option value="bank">bank</option>
            <option value="govt">govt</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="it box"><table border="1" style="width:250px">
<tr>
<td><b>Title</td>
<td><input type="text" name="ittitle"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b> IT Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="itname"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b> IT Job Role</td>
<td><input type="text" name="itrole"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b> IT Salary</td>
<td><input type="text" name="itsalary"></td></tr>



</table></div>

<div class="bank box"><table border="1" style="width:250px">
<tr>
<td><b>Title</td>
<td><input type="text" name="btitle"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b> Bank Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="bname"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b> Bank Job Role</td>
<td><input type="text" name="brole"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b> Bank Salary</td>
<td><input type="text" name="bsalary"></td></tr>



</table></div>

<div class="govt box"><table border="1" style="width:250px">
<tr>
<td><b>Title</td>
<td><input type="text" name="gtitle"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b> Govt Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="gname"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b> Govt Job Role</td>
<td><input type="text" name="grole"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b> Govt Salary</td>
<td><input type="text" name="gsalary"></td></tr>
</table></div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should some explanations on how to solve the problem in addition to some code :)

Comment: how to write if condition to insert particular form based on category

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    <?php
    require_once("database.php");
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $category=$_POST["category"];
    $ittitle=$_POST["ittitle"];
    $itname=$_POST["itname"];
    $itrole=$_POST["itrole"];
    $itsalary=$_POST["itsalary"];

    $btitle=$_POST["btitle"];
    $bname=$_POST["bname"];
    $brole=$_POST["brole"];
    $bsalary=$_POST["bsalary"];

    $gtitle=$_POST["gtitle"];
    $gname=$_POST["gname"];
    $grole=$_POST["grole"];
    $gsalary=$_POST["gsalary"];

    $result=mysql_query("insert into test(`ittitle`,`itname`,`itrole`,`itsalary`,`btitle`,`bname`,`brole`,`bsalary`,`gtitle`,`gname`,`grole`,`gsalary`) values('$_POST[ittitle]','$_POST[itname]','$_POST[itrole]','$_POST[itsalary]','$_POST[btitle]','$_POST[bname]','$_POST[brole]','$_POST[bsalary]','$_POST[gtitle]','$_POST[gname]','$_POST[grole]','$_POST[gsalary]')");

    echo "Inserted Successfully";
    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery Show Hide Using Selectbox</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .box{
            padding: 20px;
            display: none;
            margin-top: 20px;

        }
        .it{ background: white; }
        .bank{ background: white; }
        .govt{ background: white; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select").change(function(){
                $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
                    if($(this).attr("value")=="it"){
                        $(".box").hide();
                        $(".it").show();
                    }
                    if($(this).attr("value")=="bank"){
                        $(".box").hide();
                        $(".bank").show();
                    }
                    if($(this).attr("value")=="govt"){
                        $(".box").hide();
                        $(".govt").show();
                    }
                });
            }).change();
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<form action="#">
        <div>
            <select name="category">
                <option>Choose Category</option>
                <option value="it">it</option>
                <option value="bank">bank</option>
                <option value="govt">govt</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="it box"><table border="1" style="width:250px">
    <tr>
    <td><b>Title</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ittitle"></td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td><b> IT Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="itname"></td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td><b> IT Job Role</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="itrole"></td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td><b> IT Salary</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="itsalary"></td></tr>



    </table></div>

    <div class="bank box"><table border="1" style="width:250px">
    <tr>
    <td><b>Title</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="btitle"></td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td><b> Bank Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="bname"></td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td><b> Bank Job Role</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="brole"></td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td><b> Bank Salary</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="bsalary"></td></tr>



    </table></div>

    <div class="govt box"><table border="1" style="width:250px">
    <tr>
    <td><b>Title</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="gtitle"></td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td><b> Govt Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="gname"></td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td><b> Govt Job Role</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="grole"></td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td><b> Govt Salary</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="gsalary"></td></tr>
    </table></div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @user3564915 : your code is not sql injection free.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=mysql_query("insert into test(ittitle,itname,itrole,itsalary,btitle,bname,brole,bsalary,gtitle,gname,grole,gsalary)
values('$ittitle','$itname','$itrole','$itsalary','$btitle','$bname','$brole','$bsalary','gtitle','$gname','$grole','$gsalary')");
```